# Difference Natzar and Shamar?

Tags: words, tehilim-psalms, mishlei

What is the difference between נצר natzar (keep, gaurd, watch, preserve) and שמר shamar?

Their meaning looks so similar that I would like to know what makes the difference between these two.

(For example in the verse of [Tehillim 105:45](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16326#v=45), [Mishlei 2:8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16373#v=8), [2:11](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16373#v=11), [4:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16375#v=6) etc.)

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11142/5323

Comment: ? That's about goel, could you explain your meaning with this link ?

Comment: @J.Levi I didn't see your comment, because I wasn't [`@pung`](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2067/5323). I just wanted to point out that if people thought that this was a low-quality question, that there is a similar (very highly voted) question that was asked a while ago, and deemed on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Malbim (ביאור המילות) [writes](http://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_Beur_Hamilot_on_Psalms.105.45) on your first cited verse ([Tehillim 105:45](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16326#v=45)):

> **ישמרו, ינצרו.** הנוצר גדול מן השומר, והתורות צריכים שמירה יתירה יותר כי הם כוללות גם עקרי האמונה והלמודים
>
> "נצר" is a greater degree of "guarding" than "שמר;" because the תורות
>   need to be guarded more because they also contain the main tenets of
>   our faith and learning.

(*my translation*)